# NMF algorithm, matrix subscript meaning

Tags: linear-programming, matrix-decomposition

I have the following algorithm that I'm trying to implement:

$$H_{am} \leftarrow H_{am}\frac{ \sum_{i}W_{ia}X_{im}/(W \cdot H)_{im}}{\sum_{k}W_{ka} }$$

Where for example $X$ is a of size 5 x 10, $H$ is of size 2 x 10 and $W$ is of size 5 x 2.

What is the meaning of the subscript symbols $_{a}$ and $_{m}$ within the summation notation and outside of it? I thought initially the $_{a}$ and $_{m}$ were exactly the dimensions of $H$ (2 x 10) so in the case of the $W$ denominator this would be every row of $W$ iteratively $_{k}:$(1-5) of column $_{a}$(2), however following the same logic and updating the final element of $H_{am}$ with the result seems bizarre and doesn't work.

I also thought that $_a$ and $_{m}$ may have meant all the rows/columns respectively but that doesn't really make much sense with the $_{i}$/$_{k}$ and even if it was a selected vector the element wise multiplication would be a mismatch of sizes e.g $W$ and $X$.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: $H_{am}$ is a real number

Comment: It will be the real numbers stored in the final row and column? I have tried this but little to no optimisation of the algorithm takes place

Comment: Each term except $W.H$ is a real number. Optimization is another subject. Check it works and minimizes the objective function (KL divergence), look at the derivation, and compare with the alternating least square algorithm.

Comment: I understand that. What I don't understand is 1: Is $H_{am}$ the final row/column of H that is updated by multiplying by the outcome of the rest of the algorithm and 2: Is $W_{ia}$ all the rows of the second column? I need to check i'm implementing it correctly before I do any comparisons